# How can I create a custom repository in Prisma 2 using NestJS like TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, prisma2

In TypeORM I can create a CustomRepository like it:

```js
import {EntityRepository, Repository} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "../entity/User";

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {

    findByName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        return this.findOne({ firstName, lastName });
    }

}
```

How can I reach the same result using Prisma 2 and NestJS ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make exactly same thing like using entityRepository.

but, you can make it in PrismaService class

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {       

    async onModuleInit() {
      await this.$connect();
    }
    async onModuleDestroy() {
      await this.$disconnect();
    }

    findByName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
      return this.findOne({ firstName, lastName });
    }
}
```

then you can run like below

```
in your class.ts
class something {
  constructor(private readonly prisma : PrismaService){}
  
  findName(){
    this.prisma.findByName(something);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this approach is that within the same file reference would be made to functions that would be used by different modules, which is not scalable. On the other hand, I don't know if you really have a good solution for this as TypeORM.